# Transpiled typescript unexpectedly adding 'default' export object

Tags: typescript, import

Long-time C++ guy, recent web-dev guy.  My application has a .js file that returns an object:

```
define('moduleA', [...], function(...) {
    ...
    return {
        propertyA: /*boolean value*/,
        ...
    };
});
```

The ellipses are irrelevant for this question.  Now I have a .ts file where I'm trying to import this Javascript module and reference it in the Typescript code.  My Typescript looks something like:

```
//@ts-ignore
import moduleA from 'moduleA';

export class ModuleB {
    ...
    public someMethod() {
        if (moduleA.propertyA) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

When this Typescript is transpiled, the Require statement at the top is correct, but the transpiled code in 'someMethod' above is:

```
if (module_a_1.default.propertyA) {
    ...
}
```

I don't understand where this 'default' sub-object is coming from.  As it is now, an exception is thrown when running because 'propertyA' cannot be referenced on 'undefined'.  If the 'default' wasn't there and the transpiled code was:

```
if (module_a_1.propertyA) {
    ...
}
```

Then it should work.  I'm guessing this is some rookie mistake with Typescript.  Can anyone offer insight?  Thanks in advance!

- Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
import * as moduleA from 'moduleA';
```

Comment: Hello -

It changes the transpiled code, but still have the same issue.  I have this now:

    `if (module_a_1.moduleA.propertyA) {`

Note that now instead of 'default', it adds a 'moduleA' sub-object which is the reference name I gave it in the import statement.  I'm still trying to access 'propertyA' on an undefined object because it should be:

    `if (module_a_1.propertyA) {`

to work properly.  Note that 'module_a_1' is the generated name the Typescript transpiler gives in the Require statement.

Comment: @Steve Can you touch the .js file? It uses an old AMD module system, I am not much familiar with it. Would be so easy if it used es6 modules or at least commonJS

Comment: Hi Nurbol... thanks for the quick reply.  The .js is ours but I'm trying to use it as-is.  It works fine if importing it into another .js file.  Just trying to get it to work in the .ts file.

Comment: Looks like you edited your answer.  And your updated answer does indeed work.  Thank you!  I'm still catching on with this stuff.